# sql search in only parts of a string

Tags: sql

I have a comma separated list of names in a database called owners (sometimes there is one owner sometimes there are multiple owners... if there are more than 1 the names are comma separated). I want to find whether a certain name appears as the first name in the owners field. 
So I need to search for a pattern as e.g. with the like command in sql, but I need to restrict it to the part before the first comma. Note that I want that the entry

John Doe, Katrin

is found if my pattern is "John". Is that possible at all? 
I am looking for a solution in sqlalchemy, but if there is a solution in sql I am sure I can find the sqlalchemy version myself.
thanks
carl

Comment: Is there any possibility you could redesign your tables so that you have a one-to-many relationship to an `Owners` table?  It will make queries like this a LOT easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away with using `LIKE` as it is as the front of the string. The `%` match anything. Here it is in `sqlalchemy`

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.like('THENAME,%'))
```

If you want to match just "Jon Doe" with just "Jon" you will need a regex

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.op('regexp')('r^Jon[^,]*,'))
```

This will match anything starting `^` with `Jon` followed by any number of non `,` chars `[^,]*` followed by `,`

Comment: would this pick up the John Doe entry if THENAME is only John?

Comment: No for that you would need regex.

Comment: Updated for that regex.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server, you could do:

```
select colname
where substring(lower(colname), 1, charindex(',',lower(colname))-1) like '%john%'
```

You could do the same in Oracle as

```
select colname
where substr(lower(colname), 1, instr(lower(colname),',')-1) like '%john%'
```

As you can see the functions are specific to databases.

Comment: Replace the 2nd & 3rd  instances of colname with colname+',' to get around the issue of single names without commas.